# Unsubscribe links have missing slash

Tags: civimail, unsubscribe

This one has me perplexed since I haven't seen the missing link issue cause any other problems. In the Civimail unsubscribe links, there's a missing slash right after the domain URL. For example, assume a domain of mycivisite.dom. When the ubsubscribe link is generated in the emails, it looks like this:

http://mycivisite.domcivicrm/mailing/optout/yaddayadda/etc

As you can see, there's no slash between mycivisite.dom and civicrm. Where am I not looking?

-- Marcel

Answer (score 2):

I would check `civicrm.settings.php` for the `CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` to ensure it has a trailing slash.

If you update your question with your CMS and the CiviCRM version, there might be more specific advice folks can give.